# Issue when trying to highlight ListView row item onClick

Tags: android, listview

When I click on each row in my ListView, I would like the TextView inside the row to become bold, and that works perfectly, but the problem I am facing is that when I click on another item in my ListView, the other row item is still bold as well as the one that was just selected

How can I put the last selected ListView row TextView's typeface back to NORMAL after another has been selected? thanks.

Here's my code:

```
    @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);



    TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.songTextView);
    TextView artist = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.artistTextView);


       name.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
       artist.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);


}
```

Comment: try by making name and artist textviews global and before initializing by name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.songTextView); check if null then initialize else make typeface.normal and then initialize

Comment: try to use selector might be your issue get resolved.

Comment: are you using adapter to show Listview data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way to achieve this is to add a member to the adaper with the position of the *bolded* row, init it with -1. 
At your *onItemClickListener* call the adapter and set the field to the pressed position, and then call *notifiyDataSetChanged*. At you adapter on the *getview* check if the current position is bold or by the bold_position field in the adapter.

some code:

adaper:

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends ...{

int mBoldPos = -1;
public void setBoldPos(int newPos)
{
 this.mBoldPos = newPos;
}
```

fragment-

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ....)
{
  onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
  {
   ((CustomAdapter) mListView.getAdapter()).setBoldPos(position);
   ((CustomAdapter) mListView.getAdapter()).notifiyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```

adapter:

```
getView(..)
{
if (pos == mBoldPos)
  {
    // Bold me up
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "add a member to the adaper with the position of the bolded row, init it with -1." Shall I create a method called "mBoldPos" that returns an int? and how do I initialize it with -1? thanks.